# Loading bar freezes when loading Jar

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to implement a loading bar that (through javascript) receives callbacks from Java.

When receiving the current status, I print it to the console, and also change the text of the loading bar.

```
window.LoadingState = function (status,a,b,c,d,e,f,g)   
{
   console.log("LoadingState");
   console.log(status,a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
   LOADBAR.innerHTML=status;
}
```

The status prints fine in the browser console, but the loading bar text is only updated after the Jar file has been downloaded (It only shows 100% and nothing in between)

I call back to Js using the following line of code at multiple places within my Java:

```
window.call("LoadingState", new Object[]{50,"Updater"});
```

And it is received in the console as shown below, but only updated on screen when the Jar has been loaded.

[image: Console]

Is there a way to get around this freeze?

Comment: What exactly is the status bar supposed to display? From your text I figure it is the download progress of a jar file. Please be more specific, as to how you generate the values for your function call.

Comment: The status bar currently only displays a value between 0 and 100, I want to make a progress bar out of it. This was my first test in which I found that the rendering freezes although (proven by the console) the javascript executes. I will update the question to show how I call back to Js.

Comment: It does show 100 when the Jar file has finished loading, but no values in between..